# embed ttf as embeded resource: can't reference it

Tags: c#, resources, truetype

I've just added a ttf file to the project (c# 2008 express) as "file" and build option to embedded resource.

I'm having problems when trying to set this font like this:
(I know the next line is wrong...)

```
this.label1.Font = AlarmWatch.Properties.Resources.Baby_Universe;
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'byte[]' to
>   'System.Drawing.Font' C:\Users\hongo\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\AlarmWatch\AlarmWatch\Form1.Designer.cs 57  32  AlarmWatch

I know it is byte[] cause I've set the option build as embedded resource, but comparing with this line that is correct:

```
this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("OCR A Extended",
                           24F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                           System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

How can I set this.label1 to use the new font?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `AddMemoryFont` method in the `System.Drawing.Text` namespace, which loads a font from a memory (it takes a pointer to the memory block, so you'll need to do some unsafe operation to get pointer to your byte array - I found an [example here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141224204810/http://bobpowell.net/embedfonts.aspx)). More about the [method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addmemoryfont.aspx).

There is also a related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955629/c-using-an-embedded-font-on-a-textbox) showing how to import Win API function to load the font directly (in case the above .NET method doesn't work).

**EDIT** A translation of the key part from Visual Basic might look like this (haven't checked it though):

```
// This should be probably a field of some class
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

// allocate memory and copy byte[] to the location
IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(yourByteArray.Length);
Marshal.Copy(yourFontArray, 0, data, yourFontArray.Length);

// pass the font to the font collection
pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontStream.Length)

// Free the unsafe memory
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data)
```

Once you have this, you should be able to refer to the font using its usual name.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I went to that page but, I don't know how to put that code in my application because it is in visual basic and cannot translate it well...

Comment: I get the correct name, size and style...but  if I try to set the font to a label it won't do it, it goes back to the default font instead.
the line i like this
label1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0].Name,15f);
I placed the lines you gave me in the form_load method, and try to set the label in that block of code right after those lines....

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void AddFontFromResource(PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection, string fontResourceName)
{
    var fontBytes = GetFontResourceBytes(typeof (App).Assembly, fontResourceName);
    var fontData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontBytes.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(fontBytes, 0, fontData, fontBytes.Length);
    privateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont(fontData, fontBytes.Length);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontData);
}

private static byte[] GetFontResourceBytes(Assembly assembly, string fontResourceName)
{
    var resourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fontResourceName);
    if (resourceStream == null)
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to find font '{0}' in embedded resources.", fontResourceName));
    var fontBytes = new byte[resourceStream.Length];
    resourceStream.Read(fontBytes, 0, (int)resourceStream.Length);
    resourceStream.Close();
    return fontBytes;
}
```