# How can I change the Font of a Range when I have a FontFamily?

Tags: c#

I used this function in the below link to get a font. But I will use the font in a word file.

[addFontFile from Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources)

I tried

```
myRange.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0],18,FontStyle.Regular);
```

But `Range.Font` doesn't allow this.(C#) How can I assign my font family to the Range's font?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to give Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Font font family. Is it even possible?