# How to create a custom label in WPF to be then used in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I would like to use a custom font for a Label in my WinForms project without installing the font. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources) as a solution, however it does not work since the FontStyle I want to use is Thin, which is not included in the System.Drawing.FontStyle enumerator.

Since I read instead that it should be quite easy in WPF to use such a custom font, I thought that a possible solution is to create a custom label (ThinLabel) in WPF and to host it in Winforms. Can you please instruct me on which is the proper way to create a custom label in WPF for this purpose? I read that in WPF controls can be customized in several ways (Styles, Data Templates,..) but I've no idea of which should be taken for this purpose. Please consider I've never used WPF so far.

Comment: in your toolbox you should see a WPFElementHost.

Comment: That I know, but the question is on how to create a custom control in WPF for that purpose. Have I to create a custom control or just to use Styles? Can you make an example?

Answer (score 0):

In Order to implement WPF UserControls in Winforms you need to use and ElementHost
So if you want to create an WPF Label like you said in WPF you create a DLL project with your label inside it and reference it in your winforms project, after building you should be able to see a the UserControl with the label in the toolbox if not use an ElementHost