# Which ContentEncoding to be used for WOFF and TTF with HttpListener response?

Tags: truetype, httplistener, woff

Chrome and Firefox don't render Font-Awesome's WOFF/TTF, even if they download them from HttpListener, that said, Safari on iOS is rendering Font-Awesome correctly.
I am sending HTTP response using .NET's HttpListener class as follows:

```
private void Send(HttpListenerContext context, byte[] response, string contentType)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = response.Length;
        context.Response.AddHeader("Server", SERVER);

        if (response == null || response.Length == 0)
        {
            logger.Error("Send: Engine generated null or empty content");
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            return;
        }

        using (var s = context.Response.OutputStream)
        {
            s.Write(response, 0, response.Length);
        }
    }
```

Is there another encoding type (other than UTF8) for WOFF? or is there something that I have to take care of in Chrome or Firefox?

Any help or pointer appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my own implementation, I leave out the ContentEncoding header all together when serving a font or binary.

This should work:

```
context.Response.ContentLength64 = response.Length;
context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-font-woff";
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(response, 0, response.Length);

context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it did not work for me. My fonts are still not showing. Chrome still shows `failed to decode downloaded font`

Comment: What is your take on this: I have the woff, eot, ttf files as `Embedded Resources` in my CS project. Is it likely, that .NET might be converting this font files to UTF-8 encoding while converting the file to an `Embedded Resource` while I get the bytes of fonts files through `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had all the www content as `Embedded Resource`, and I created a method to convert those `Embedded Resource` `Stream` to a `byte` array by first converting that to a `string` using `UTF-8` encoding. 
So [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources) helped me to pinpoint the root cause. Once I converted the `Embedded Resource` `Stream` directly to a `byte` array, Chrome started showing Font-Awesome fonts correctly!