# why not supported font style works in windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, fonts, windows-10

```
System.Drawing.Font font = new Font("Aharoni", 20f, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Above code works in windows 10 but fails in windows 7.
Can anyone please provide root cause why this works in windows 10?

Comment: Have you tried checking your font content in Windows 7? You can simply click start and type **Fonts** on your search box. This will lead you to a folder containing all the font type in the control panel and check whether **Aharoni** exist or not.

Comment: Yes, Aharoni font is available in both OS.

Comment: I found in my pc running on Win7, the font is **Aharoni Bold** instead of  **Aharoni**. I am not sure whether this makes any difference

Comment: This will not make any difference, It throws exception message as regular font style is not supported for Aharoni in windows 7 but works in windows 10

Comment: Perhaps, you can try to change the font type to **Aharoni Bold** in your code and try to run in your Windows 7 machine. Maybe you can see something...

Answer (score 0):

That can be missing from windows 7
here [font list in windows 7](https://www.prepressure.com/fonts/basics/windows-7-font-handling/list)

To fix the problem you can add fonts you want to **Resources** [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources)

Comment: Font is not missing. In your list see first font is Aharoni.
Which works in regular style for windows 10 but not in windows 7.

Comment: can be missing from windows 7 that you have been tested on it ,try on another PC or you can try second choice by add font to **Resources** to run for all OS