# VS2017 resource files for fonts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, embedded-resource

I have already tried [addFontFile from Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources) and it didn't help me. I've also tried to find other pages on this topic to no avail.

I have two font files (.ttf) that I've included as resource files in my VS2017 project. Now I need to load these files (I'm using iTextSharp). I don't see how to do it. It's clearly not as simple as

```
font = BaseFont.CreateFont("Resources/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

because that fires an exception.

Does anyone know how to read a .ttf resource from within Visual Studio? Thanks.

Comment: *"that fires an exception..."* I can't see the exception message and stack trace. And did you even try using `GetManifestResourceStream()` as indicated in your linked post?

Comment: Did you try the second answer in your linked SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23658552/1291628

Comment: Somewhat. What I need is to access the *file*. That question deals with Streams.

Comment: but if its compiled in as a resource, its not a file any more

Comment: That's a good comment, @BugFinder. But I don't think I can use a stream to create a new font. I could use the stream to create a file, but this is going to run on Azure, and I doubt I have permissions to write to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, so to anyone who wants to do this, you just need two lines:

```
byte[] fontRegular = Properties.Resources.OpenSans_Regular;
BaseFont font = BaseFont.CreateFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, BaseFont.CACHED, fontRegular, null);
```

This assumes that the .ttf file is a resource in your project, and it is named OpenSans-Regular.ttf. This lets you use the font in iTextSharp. Enjoy!