# Embedding a font in a standalone exe

Tags: c#, console, styling

I want to create a console application but it will sometimes display a large amount of text that I will need to read. So I want to make it to use a custom font that will be more readable (for example like Roboto).

The problem is that firstly I want it to display it wherever the exe is launched (even if the computer doesn't have Roboto installed), and secondly I want the entire program to be a standalone exe, which means that including the font in a local folder and importing it is not an option.

I tried to search google and other forums but I couldn't find a solution that fits.
If anyone can think of a solution please do tell...

Comment: @MarcGravell dont think that is going to work for a console app

Comment: Some links I found, how to load font into PrivateFontCollection from resource - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources - how to change console font - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8 (example in documentation, including p/invoke methods), cobbling this together might work.

Comment: Try a different terminal [Top 15 Terminals](https://www.puttygen.com/windows-terminal-emulators)   ConEmu you can customise fonts

Comment: @leppie console app? wow, I didn't read that; yeah, abandon all hope! (if you need or want to control the font: you're not a console app)

Comment: @Mahan.A this would've worked if I didn't want to make it a standalone exe that will execute the same on my computers... your solution would require me to install a whole new terminal in the computer I want to run my program on which will be even more of an hassle than installing a font....