# How can I add a custom font into my .NET console application?

Tags: c#, fonts, resources, console-application

I created a program to add a text on an image with a custom font "Lucida Calligraphy". I have added the font file into my solution folder. However, at runtime it does not reflect the font. What am I missing?

1. I have added font file in my solution folder

   Property set as BuildAction: Resource and Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always
2. My .csproj reflects this as shown below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <Resource Include="Fonts\Lucida-Calligraphy-Italic.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

My `Program.cs` code looks like this:

```
// Load the image
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"E:\PrintImage\2.png");
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

// Define text color
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

// Define text font
Font arial = new Font("{StaticResource Lucida-Calligraphy-Italic}", 45);

// Text to display
string text = "Hellow World!!";

// Define rectangle
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(400, 1500, 1600, 150);

// Specify rectangle border
//Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, 2);

// Draw rectangle
//graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);

// Draw text on image
graphics.DrawString(text, arial, brush, rectangle);

// Save the output file
bitmap.Save(@"E:\OutputImage\2.png");
```

When I run the program, an output image with text on it is created, but the font doesn't correspond to the one I added as a resource. How can I get it to show the text in the corresponding font?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addFontFile from Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949057/addfontfile-from-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set your font file to Build action - Content. You also need to install "Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always".

Use the PrivateFontCollection class, which allows you to create a font from a file.
In the AddFontFile method, specify the name of the font file. You can specify the full path, or a relative.

Since you are working with unmanaged resources, such as Bitmap, Graphics and PrivateFontCollection and so on, do not forget to wrap them in a using block, or call the Dispose method to avoid memory leaks.

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"1.png"))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        using (var privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection())
        {
            privateFontCollection.AddFontFile(@"Lucida Calligraphy Italic.ttf");

            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
            {
                // Provide the path to the font on the filesystem
                using (Font customFont = new Font(privateFontCollection.Families.First(), 45))
                {
                    // Text to display
                    string text = "Hellow World!!";

                    // Define rectangle
                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);

                    // Specify rectangle border
                    //Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, 2);

                    // Draw rectangle
                    //graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);

                    // Draw text on image
                    graphics.DrawString(text, customFont, brush, rectangle);

                    // Save the output file
                    bitmap.Save(@"2.png");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `bitmap.Save(@"2.jpg");` -> you're creating a PNG image file with the .jpg extension -- The Brush object is also disposable

Comment: @Jimi I read a JPG file and save it in JPG too, so I think everything is logical. with regards to Brush, I agree. Font can also be included in the list of unmanaged resources, it also needs to be destroyed.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of image you have loaded. When you use this overload of the `Save()` method (i.e., you don't specify an ImageFormat), you create a PNG image, which is the default format. Just open the image in Notepad (or, better, an Hex Editor) and check the first bytes of the image file. The format of the **new image file** you have created is right there

Comment: @Jimi interesting feature of GDI+, thanks for the clarification.