# Creating new Font object does not take into consideration the font name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, fonts, barcode

I have the next line of code:

```
Font font = new Font("Free 3 of 9", barcodeSize, FontStyle.Regular, graphicsUnit);
```

The new created font object looks like this:

[image]

The "Free 3 of 9" font is installed on my computer and when I use this font it doesn't use the "Free 3 of 9" font name.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You have to add the font to your font resources.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297264/using-custom-fonts-on-a-label-on-winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think this happens because the font is cached by IIS.

I was using this into a MVC3 web application and after I closed and reopened the solution it worked.