# AddFontFile error: file not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862391) for my project, but failed to start because of the file not found error.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: File not found.
```

Here is my code:

```
PrivateFontCollection modernFont = new PrivateFontCollection();
            modernFont.AddFontFile("digital.ttf");
            label5.Font = new Font(modernFont.Families[0], 40);
```

The font file is located right in the namespace directory, is there something wrong with the the file path or else?

Comment: its not looking in the namespace for your font. Its looking in the executing direcotry. Place your font in the bin/debug folder and it will work

Comment: I think you have to placed your font file inside the directory of executable path.

Comment: @EpicKip I see, it worked now, but what I wanted to achieve is to include the font in the exe itself, is it possible to do that?

Comment: @HelenClayton It is possible but I'm not sure how.

Comment: for that you have to add your font file to resource file and then its available to exe.