# Ugly font rendering

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, rendering

I have been trying to get a custom font on my WinForm application. However, it seems whatever I do, the font won't render properly. It is a `.ttf` and does display on my label, just not very well.

I followed this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520042/11350546) but this is the result I am getting:

> The two labels at the bottom '0%' & '2.6MB' are both 'Courier New'. I will switch them over once I have got my top label rendering correctly.

[image: Ugly font render]

My code is near identical to the aforementioned answer (all of the bellow runs in **FormLoad**):

```
// Create a private font collection object.
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

// Select the font from 'Resources'.
// My font here is "Volter__28Goldfish_29.ttf".
int fontLength = Properties.Resources.Volter__28Goldfish_29.Length;

// Create a buffer to read in to.
byte[] fontdata = Properties.Resources.Volter__28Goldfish_29;

// Create an unsafe memory block for the font data.
IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontLength);

// Copy the bytes to the unsafe memory block.
Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, fontLength);

// Pass the font to the font collection.
pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontLength);

// Set custom font.
lblUpdate.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 8);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it would be too obvious to be true... my issue was the fact that my font size was either `6F` or `8F` as, I didn't think an odd number would be the correct size. All I had to do was change it to `7F`.

So I will keep this post up as a word of warning, if your pixel font looks ugly. Double check you've put the correct font size in.

(**Note:** Your font may also appear somewhat distorted if you haven't set the property `UseCompatibleTextRendering` to `True`)